Tally XML API issue
Here in the below schema i want to get the data of vouchers , stockitems, customer, but we can only type of data , but i need all them in one single response.
I want to get the data based on the alterid related to vouchers.
This is the schema i used
<ENVELOPE>
    <HEADER>
        <VERSION>1</VERSION>
        <TALLYREQUEST>EXPORT</TALLYREQUEST>
        <TYPE>COLLECTION</TYPE>
        <ID>CUSTOMCOLLECTION</ID>
    </HEADER>
    <BODY>
        <DESC>
            <STATICVARIABLES>
                <SVEXPORTFORMAT>$$SysName:XML</SVEXPORTFORMAT>
            </STATICVARIABLES>

            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMVOUCHERDATA">
                        <TYPE>VOUCHER</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>VOUCHERNUMBER,DATE,ISCANCELLED,PARTYNAME,PARTYLEDGERNAME,PARTYGSTIN,CONSIGNEEGSTIN,ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST.LEDGERNAME,AMOUNT,VCHSTATUSDATE,EFFECTIVEDATE,ALTERID,MASTERID,VOUCHERKEY,VOUCHERRETAINKEY,GUID,BASICSHIPDOCUMENTNO,BASICFINALDESTINATION,BASICSHIPVESSELNO,EICHECKPOST,BILLOFLADINGNO,BILLOFLADINGDATE,BILLOFLADINGDATE,BASICSHIPPEDBY,IRN,IRNACKDATE,GSTREGISTRATION,VOUCHERTYPENAME,CMPGSTREGISTRATIONTYPE,CMPGSTSTATE,NUMBERINGSTYLE,VCHSTATUSTAXUNIT,GSTNATUREOFRETURN</FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$MASTERID > 829 AND $ALTERID > 1343 </SYSTEM>                    
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>

            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMSTOCKITEMCOL">
                        <TYPE>STOCKITEM</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>NAME,GUID,GSTAPPLICABLE,GSTDETAILS.LIST,ALTERID,MRPDETAILS.LIST,BASEUNITS,ISDELETED,OPENINGBALANCE,OPENINGRATE</FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$ALTERID > 1094</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>
            
            <TDL>
                <TDLMESSAGE>
                    <COLLECTION ISMODIFY="No" ISFIXED="No" ISINITIALIZE="No" ISOPTION="No" ISINTERNAL="No" NAME="CUSTOMLEDGERDATA">
                        <TYPE>LEDGER</TYPE>
                        <FETCH>NAME,PARENT,GUID,PARTYGSTIN,BILLCREDITPERIOD,LEDGERMOBILE,LEDGERCOUNTRYISCODE,ISDELETED,ALTERID,EMAIL,PRIORSTATENAME</FETCH>
                        <FILTER>Masterfilter</FILTER>
                    </COLLECTION>
                    <SYSTEM TYPE="Formulae" NAME="Masterfilter">$ALTERID > 32</SYSTEM>
                </TDLMESSAGE>
            </TDL>

        </DESC>
    </BODY>
</ENVELOPE>


AlterId is different for master's and voucher's
you cannot query masters data based on vouchers alterID
We can get all data at same time, but it covers more memory and may hang tally if data is more
you should mention all Sourcecollections inside <TDLMESSAGE>
and to get all types of data just mention them inside collections tag inside collection
Ex:
<Collection Name="CustCollection">
<Sourcecollections>Col1,Col2 </Sourcecollections> 
</Collection

